# Parsing a malformed jSon string

Tags: java, json

I'm using a Java Json library to convert an incoming string into a json one.
The lib is [json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/package-summary.html).

The problem is that I can't modify the source so, sometimes I can get some malformed jSon strings especially this kind of key/value strings :

```
"key":"a quoted "value" "
```

(this is a simplified example)

As you can see, there are double quotes surrounding the value.

So, is there an API that can replace automatically the inner double quotes with backslash ones?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean you get invalid json as input and you want to correct it?

Comment: Yes. If it can add some backslashes, it would be nice ;)

Answer (score 4):

Well, there can't be. For example, what does the following (malformed example) mean:

```
"key":"is this a value?","another key":"is this a value too?"
```

In your condition it might be either:

```
"key":"is this a value?","another key":"is this a value too?"
^k1   ^v1                ^k2           ^v2
```

or:

```
"key\":\"is this a value?\",\"another key":"is this a value too?"
^k1                                        ^v1
```

Comment: For me, a key is a double quoted string followed by a colon (":") .

Comment: @Pen - but what if the key contains double quoted strings (escaped) and colons?

Comment: @MByD - Well, the only part that is concerned is the value one.

Comment: Pen, actually, I could give the same example regarding the value.. there is a built in ambiguity, that's why the escapes are needed...

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple parser which looks for `"` which is not followed by a `,`, `:` or a `}` or other valid character and quote it and the next `"` occurrence. That would leave MByD's example untouched, but change you example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is no keys containnig ':' and ',' you can use following:

```
String repaired = broken.replaceAll("([^,{:])\"([^,:]})", "$1\\\\\"$2");
```

Here we escape only that quotes that are not following ',' ':' and '{' and not followed by ',' ':' '}'